# How to return mutiple data from a method in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I was trying to retrieve data from excel file and storing in to a datatable.It worked well for file with single sheet .But if an excel file contains multilple sheets i have to retrieve all values from sheets.Main problem now i am facing is some sheets contains same column name with other sheets.if i store it in a single datatable i will get duplicate columnname exception.How to solve this problems.I thought of to return table for each sheet by using `tuple` and `params` but no luck any idea to solve this issue.. code for single sheet which was working well is shown below

I created an extension method like below

```
public static DataTable getDataTableFromExcel(string path)
{
    using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            bool hasHeader = true; // adjust it accordingly( i've mentioned that this is a simple approach)
            string ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
            }
            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
            for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                var row = tbl.NewRow();
                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                {
                    row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
        return tbl;
    }
}
```

for reading  all sheets i changed line `var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();`
to `var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets;` and iterated collection but end with duplicate column exception since multiple sheets having same column names.Any code change to share ?

**UPDATE**

for iterating collection i did like shown below

```
public static DataTable Exceltotable(this string path)
        {
            using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
            {
                DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        pck.Load(stream);
                    }
                    var wss = pck.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    foreach (var ws in wss)
                    {
                        bool hasHeader = true; // adjust it accordingly( i've mentioned that this is a simple approach)
                        string ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
                        foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                        {

                                if ((firstRowCell.Text != "MAXIMO FIELD NAME") && (firstRowCell.Text != "Sr NO") && (firstRowCell.Text != "Sr NO"))
                                {
                                    tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
                                }


                        }
                        var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
                        for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                        {
                            var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                            var row = tbl.NewRow();
                            foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                            {
                                row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                            }
                            tbl.Rows.Add(row);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
```

**UPDATE**

calling code is shown below

DataTable dt = Extensionexcel.Exceltotable(@"D:\sample.xlsx");

Comment: `params` is for input. Tuple is for multiple output objects so why didn't this work? What about a collection? Or `out` parameters?

Comment: @Grant WinneyI updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could return a `DataSet` containing list of tables instead of `DataTable`. Each table in your DataSet would represent a sheet in excel.

Your code will be something like this:

```
public static DataSet Exceltotable(this string path)
{
    using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            pck.Load(stream);
        }

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        var wss = pck.Workbook.Worksheets;
        foreach (var ws in wss)
        {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            //Populate the datatable here
            ...
           dataSet.Tables.Add(tbl);
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to assign each sheet values to dataset table?how that syncronization i can do?

Comment: @peter You need to loop through the excel sheets, create table for each sheet, add it to `DataSet` using `DatasSet.Tables.Add`. I guess instead of `pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First()` you need to loop through it and repeat the same procedure.

Comment: return type need to change

Comment: @peter That's a typo, apart from that, does that works?

Answer (score 3):

Hi peter Why don't you just return IEnumerable< DataTable > ?

notice that .First is a method you use on a IEnumerable to get a single item.
if you stop using first. then you have the whole collection.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of returning a DataTable, why not update the method to return a DataSet, consisting of a DataTable for each sheet in the Excel document.

Comment: But how to assign each sheet values to dataset table?how that syncronization i can do?

Comment: Alter your code at the top to: 
`public static DataTable Exceltotable(this string path)
        {
            DateSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
            {
                DataTable tbl = new DataTable();`

Then at the end, add each `DataTable` to your `ds` `DataSet`:

`ds.Tables.Add(tbl);`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking? You already have the code to put a sheet into a DataTable. So you just need to add each table to a DataSet.